# How does super work in the case of the code below? (java)

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, super

```
public class Magenta
{
    public void m3()
    {
        System.out.println("Magenta 3");
        m2();
    }
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("Magenta 2");
    }
}
public class Yellow extends Magenta
{
    public void m1()
    {
        System.out.println("Yellow 1");
        super.m2();
    }
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("Yellow 2");
    }
}
public class Key extends Yellow
{
    public void m2()
    {
        System.out.println("Key 2");
    }
}
```

Why is it that if I construct a Key object

(Using `Yellow var1 = new Key();`) and

`call m1();`,

why doesn't it print `Yellow1\nYellow2?` Instead it prints `Yellow 1\nMagenta` 2,

which suggest that the call to super on the Key object is actually not called on the Key object.

I'm confused as to how super works here I thought it'd make it be interpreted as key's superclass,

which is Yellow, would be calling m2();.

Answer (score 3):

When you are calling `m1()` on a `Key` instance, the method `m1` of class `Yellow` is called as it is inherited by the `Key` class and not overridden inside it.

So if you look inside `m1()` of `Yellow`, it will first print `"Yellow 1"` and then it will call the superclass `Magenta`'s method `m2()` which will print `"Magenta 2"`.

Here is a visualization:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You;re instantiating an object of class `Yellow` and calling `m1` method. This works as follows:

```
System.out.println("Yellow 1");
super.m2();
```

So it prints `"Yellow 1"` and calls `m2` of superclass, which is `Magenta`, so:

```
System.out.println("Magenta 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Super keyword denotes object of Super Class ,

So when you call `super.m2()` its calls goes to Super class method `m2();`

if you call m2() method of yellow class simply call `m2()` without using `super`.

**Super Keyword in Java**

> The super keyword in java is a reference variable that is used to
>   refer parent class objects.
>
> Use of super with variables: This scenario occurs when a derived class
>   and base class has same data members.
>
> Use of super with methods: This is used when we want to call parent
>   class method.